# Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.3) with .NET framework 4.8

Tags: .net, tls1.2, interface-implementation, tls1.3, .net-4.8

We are using two project

1. CommonInterFaces (Developed using .NET 4)
2. InterfaceImplementation (Recompile using .NET 4.8)

Previously we were using TLS 1.2, but it will eventually be replaced by the newest released standard TLS 1.3.
For same reason we have complied InterfaceImplementation to .NET framework 4.8, but not the CommonInterfaces(Only Deceleration).

So My question is, Do I need to recompile CommonInterface project to .NET 4.8 version, or will it be fine if implementation is complied against 4.8.

Please provide guideline.

Thank You.

Comment: If those are only declarations and if there is no harm in upgrading them also to .NET Framework 4.8, then you should upgrade.

Comment: @AnkushJain If we upgrade it will affect existing consumer and there will be complete rebuild of all project to everyone .